# Trying to store multiple values from a SELECT to use in a DELETE

Tags: sql, oracle

Ok, so basically I need to select multiple IDs from one column, then use those IDs to delete from a table.

At the moment I'm trying to do something like this but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or even in the right ballpark.

```
--this will return multiple rows
select user_group_user_id, user_group_id
bulk collect into USERGROUPUSERID, USERGROUPID
from user_group_user_tab
where user_id = USERID; --USERID is argument passed in

--Attemting to delete multiple rows where the above results are found 
delete from user_group_user_tab 
where user_group_user_id in USERGROUPUSERID;

delete from user_group_tab
where user_group_id in USERGROUPID;
```

This is all part of a stored procedure in Oracle (11g).  USERGROUPUSERID and USERGROUPID are declared earlier on.

Anyone have some suggestions on how to accomplish this? I'm not sure if that bulk collect is the way to go or if there's a totally different approach, or if I'm just flat wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally use

```
BEGIN TRANS
delete from OrderItems where OrderId in ( SELECT OrderId FROM Orders WHERE CustomerName like '%peter%'); 
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE CustomerName like '%peter%'; 
COMMIT;
```

i.e. just running deletes over subquery results. Temporary tables as per "ask tom" ain't used like that in oracle, and cursor over each row would be a lot slower than simple join. On top of it I think oracle optimiser is smart enuff to cache temporary dataset  ( SELECT OrderId FROM Orders WHERE CustomerName like '%peter%')

[Ask Tom about temp tables and cursors](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1164655862293)

Comment: Simple and to the point and it did the trick.  SQL's not my strong suit, but I feel I should have known that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a cursor to retrieve all your values and use `WHERE CURRENT OF` [sentence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php).

Your cursor will look like this:

```
cursor c1 (USERID number(10))
    is
    select user_group_user_id, user_group_id
    from user_group_user_tab
    where user_id = USERID
    for update of user_group_user_tab;
```

EDIT: The logic for this problem can be like this:

1. Create the cursor with the values you want to delete
2. Open it
3. Start fetching every row of the cursor.
4. In the fect, delete the actual row.

The link on the **sentence** word can help you to do this.

If you have issues using cursors, here is a good [introduction to Oracle 11g Cursors](http://www.dbanotes.com/database-development/introduction-to-oracle-11g-cursors/). Plus, this [blog entry](http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2007/05/oracle-plsql-cursors-with-parameters.html) has a nice example using a cursor with parameters.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with cursors.  What value(s) am I using to run the delete statements?  edit: didn't notice the link, I'll give that a read through